# Not able to filter through a to-do list

Tags: javascript, html, web, dom, addeventlistener

tying to write a code in witch you add task to a to- do list, everything good until i want to add a filte and when i click the optionts on the select element it shows the following:

```
apps.js:57 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined
    at apps.js:57
    at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLSelectElement.filterTodo (apps.js:54)
```

im trying to solve this for like 4 days, but had no success at it, i even revisited the code from the author (im following a tutorial and i've followed every step exactly like the guy who wrote it, however, the guy has no problem with the code)
im gonna add the whole code here

the name of the function im having trouble with is filterTodo

```js
const todoInput = document.querySelector(".todo-input");
const todoButton = document.querySelector(".todo-button");
const todoList = document.querySelector(".todo-list");
const filterOption = document.querySelector(".filter-todo");

todoButton.addEventListener("click", addTodo);
todoList.addEventListener("click", deleteCheck);
filterOption.addEventListener("click", filterTodo);

function addTodo(event){
  //prevenir que haga submit
  event.preventDefault();
  //hacer div
  const todoDiv = document.createElement("div");
  todoDiv.classList.add("todo");
  const newTodo = document.createElement('li');
  newTodo.innerText = todoInput.value;
  newTodo.classList.add('todo-item');
  todoDiv.appendChild(newTodo);
  //check button
  const completedButton = document.createElement('button');
  completedButton.innerHTML = '<i class = "fas fa-check"></i>'
  completedButton.classList.add("checkbtn");
  todoDiv.appendChild(completedButton);
  //del button
  const trashButton = document.createElement('button');
  trashButton.innerHTML = '<i class = "fas fa-trash"></i>'
  trashButton.classList.add("trashbtn");
  todoDiv.appendChild(trashButton);

  todoList.appendChild(todoDiv);
  todoInput.value = "";
}

function deleteCheck(e){
  const item = e.target;
  //Delete
  if (item.classList[0] === 'trashbtn'){
    const todo = item.parentElement;
    todo.classList.add('fall');
    todo.addEventListener('transitionend', function(){
    todo.remove();
    })
  }

  if (item.classList[0] === 'checkbtn'){
    const todo = item.parentElement;
    todo.classList.toggle('completed');
  }
}

function filterTodo(e) {
  const todos = todoList.childNodes;
  todos.forEach(function(todo) {
    switch (e.target.value) {
      case "all":
        todo.style.display = "flex";
        break;
      case "completed":
        if (todo.classList[0].contains("completed")) {
          todo.style.display = "flex";
        } else {
          todo.style.display = "none";
        }
        break;
      case "uncompleted":
        if (!todo.classList[0].contains("completed")) {
          todo.style.display = "flex";
        } else {
          todo.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>To-Do List</h1>
  </header>
  <form>
    <input type="text" class ="todo-input">
    <button class="todo-button" type="submit">
      <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="select">
      <select name="todos" class="filter-todo"  >
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="completed">Completed</option>
        <option value="uncompleted">Uncompleted</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="todo-container">
    <ul class="todo-list">

    </ul>

  </div>
  <script src="apps.js"></script>
</body>
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

### Node.childNodes Gives you a live Nodelist

What you were looking for was the the children property

```
function filterTodo(e) {
   const todos = Array.from(todoList.children);

   if (!todos) return;

...
}
```

The todos variable stores all the children of div.todo-list element which returns a `HTMLCollection`. An `HTMLCollection` does not have the forEach method so I had to convert it into an array using `Array.from()`

Then I ask a simple question,

If there is no children in the parentNode exit out of the function

Comment: Here's the articles to research on Node constructor [children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) and [childNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode)